# Database Schema Privileges for ATG

Tags: oracle, privileges, atg

I am setting up a new instance of ATG (version 10.0.3). I am using an Oracle database (Oracle SE ONE). I need to create the four basic database users - `atg_pub`, `atg_prod`, `atg_cata`, and `atg_catb`.

Which privileges should I assign to these users in the Oracle database?

I assume each user needs, at the minimum

- CONNECT
- CREATE/ALTER/DROP TABLE
- CREATE/ALTER/DROP INDEX

Is there a definitive list?

P.S. I am using a shared Oracle instance and do not have the privileges to GRANT ALL to these users

Comment: The Application Server also plays a role in the discussion. The way JBoss handles transactions will require more grants.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember granting CONNECT and RESOURCE roles plus some quota on the tablespace was sufficient